# How to programmatically monitor and watch for Azure Spot VM eviction and stop a service or program saving data before the VM itself is stopped?

Tags: azure, devops

I have a service that performs data analysis on Azure VM Spot instances. However, when Microsoft Azure evicts the instance, it does not stop my service gracefully. Instead, it eliminates the VM while all the services are running. Therefore, my does not send intermediary data analysis results to the server, so the progress is lost. How can I programmatically monitor and watch for Azure Spot VM eviction and stop a service or a program while saving data (sending it to the server) before the VM itself is stopped by Azure?

When Azure evicts spot virtual machines, it does so without shutting down these virtual machines. It simply stops them as they are working, causing my service to lose all the results of the data it was processing. When the eviction finally happens, the VM is terminated immediately, and all services running on it are halted. This way of eviction means that my service cannot send any intermediate data analysis results to the server, and all progress is lost. To prevent this from happening, I need to find a way to monitor Azure's Spot VM eviction process in real time and shut down my service gracefully before the VM is terminated. This will ensure that all intermediate data analysis results are saved and sent to the server before the VM is actually evicted. I analyzed the capabilities of the Microsoft Azure Linux VM Agent (waagent) and found out that it cannot monitor eviction and, thus, is unable to run a script before the VM is evicted.

Please suggest a script that can programmatically monitor whether a VM is about to be evicted, and that stops a particular Linux (Ubuntu) service.

Answer (score 0):

Azure does not notify the VM via a push notification, but there is an HTTP endpoint where a VM can query the information on whether it will be soon evicted. An application on the VM has to constantly poll the endpoint with a frequency as low as one second. Otherwise, it can miss the information, and the VM will be evicted before the software running on the VM will notice it. The applications running on the VM being evicted do not receive SIGTERM or other signals that arrive at shutdown because, at eviction, the VM is not shut down in a normal sense.

There is the [Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/instance-metadata-service) which is a REST API. This API is only accessible from within a running virtual machine instance on a non-routable IP address 169.254.169.254. You can query for [scheduled events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/scheduled-events) such as eviction. The eviction event is issued a few seconds before the actual eviction takes place. Microsoft writes that the event (notice) is issued [at least 30 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/spot-vms) before the actual eviction, but I noticed sometimes it was less time. Therefore, I personally suggest not relying on these 30 seconds but detecting the event and saving the data as soon as possible.

Here is the Python code that polls the API and stops a service and exits on an eviction note. You can actually modify the `stop_service()` function to also stop other services or perform actions required for you. Suppose you need to stop a service called "fishtest", and your hostname (`platform.node()`) is the same as the Azure VM name, and you are using a Linux kernel (`os.uname().release`) that has the word "azure" in it's release name. In this case, the script will be the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from time import sleep
import os
import platform
import requests
import json

metadataUrl = "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/scheduledevents"
headerValur = {"Metadata": "true"}
queryParams = {"api-version": "2020-07-01"}
stopStatuses = ["Scheduled", "Started"]
stopTypes = ["Reboot", "Redeploy", "Freeze", "Preempt", "Terminate"]


def get_scheduled_events():
    resp = requests.get(metadataUrl, headers=headerValur, params=queryParams)
    data = resp.json()
    return data


def stop_service():
    print("Stopping the service...")
    os.system("/usr/sbin/service fishtest stop")
    print("Stopped.")


continueLoop = True

s = os.uname().release
if "azure" in s:
    myComputer = platform.node()
    while continueLoop:
        payload = get_scheduled_events()
        if "Events" in payload.keys():
            print("Received payload", payload)
            for event in payload["Events"]:
                eventStatus = None
                if "EventStatus" in event.keys():
                    eventStatus = event["EventStatus"]
                eventType = None
                if "EventType" in event.keys():
                    eventType = event["EventType"]
                resourceType = None
                if "ResourceType" in event.keys():
                    resourceType = event["ResourceType"]
                resources = None
                if "Resources" in event.keys():
                    resources = event["Resources"]
                if (
                    (eventStatus in stopStatuses)
                    & (eventType in stopTypes)
                    & (resourceType == "VirtualMachine")
                    & (myComputer in resources)
                ):
                    print("Handling signal", eventType)
                    stop_service()
                    continueLoop = False
                    break
        if not continueLoop:
            break
        sleep(1)
```

The check on the word "azure" in the kernel release name (`if "azure" in s:`) is needed in case if the script is accidentally run on a non-Azure instance of Linux.

For your convenience, you can make this Python script to run as a service. Here is an example for Ubuntu on how can you install it as a service. Suppose you saved the above Python code to `/root/azure-monitor-eviction.py` and assigned Execute attribute to it (`chmod +x /root/azure-monitor-eviction.py`. In this case, save the following code to a filename with .bash extension, such as `installservice.bash` and run `bash installservice.bash`.

```
echo -e "[Unit]\n\
Description=Azure Monitor Eviction Service\n\
After=sshd.service\n\
[Service]\n\
Nice=4\n\
User=root\n\
WorkingDirectory=/root\n\
ExecStart=/root/azure-monitor-eviction.py\n\
[Install]\n\
WantedBy=multi-user.target" >/etc/systemd/system/azure-monitor-eviction.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable azure-monitor-eviction.service
systemctl start azure-monitor-eviction.service
```

To actually make a VM evicted to test the Python script, run the following line from Azure Shell:

```
az vm simulate-eviction --resource-group YourResourceGroupName --name YourVMName
```

Here, the command `simulate-eviction` is [misleading](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26291), as the VM is not "simulated" to be evicted but is actually evicted, i.e. if your VM has the eviction policy to delete, the VM will be actually deleted, not a "simulatedly" deleted. A better command name would have been `force-eviction`.